# Bayesian Classification evaluation

Tags: machine-learning, probability, classification, naive-bayes

I am trying to implement Bayesian Classification on the data set as follows:

"Problem: classify whether a given person is a male or a female based on the measured features. The features include height, weight, and foot size."

Example training set below (borrowed from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier)

[image]

**Testing**

Below is some samples to be classified as a male or female.

```
sex       height(feet)  weight(lbs)      foot size(inches)
sample         6            130            8
sample         4            140            5
```

**Results:**

```
Actual:'female' and the output is (0.99, 'female')
Actual:'female' and the output is (0.89, 'male')
```

Here, i want to evaluate the classification accuracy. I am confused between two options for evaluation: 
First option, it classified 1 of 2 test data correctly, so the accuracy is 50%.

Second option, the probabilities of being female are (0.99 + 0.11) /2 = 0.55, so the accuracy is 55%.

Which option makes sense to evaluate the classification accuracy of this method? What are the meaning of each options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Second option, the probabilities of being female are (0.99 + 0.11) /2 = 0.55, so the accuracy is 55%.

Thats not how numbers work...

> Which option makes sense to evaluate the classification accuracy of this method?

Well, the first one is actually measuring accuracy. The second... is confused.

> What are the meaning of each options?

The first means accuracy. The second means nothing.